# How to change offset value when new content is dynamically generated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset

We are getting the offset value of an input box when the page loads using the offset() method. However, above that input box, there's a button that shows a hidden div when clicked (and this div can have varying heights depending on the dynamic content). After that button is clicked, the offset value remains the same but now the height of the document has increased. What we want to happen is for the offset value to also dynamically change when the document height changes.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I can identify the problem you're having from the information you provided. If we could see some code or have a link to the page with the issue, it would be easier to provide an accurate solution.

It sounds like you're using jQuery's offset method to determine the location of an input box on page load. It also sounds like you're storing that value, which is not what you want. A call to offset will only provide the position of the element at the time of the call.

Instead, cache the selector like this

```
var $stored_selector = $('#your .selector');
```

And call the method on it every time you want the current position

```
// returns current position relative to the document
$stored_selector.offset();
```

Answer (score 0):

`.offset()` *is* dynamic. You're not storing the value in a variable are you? Just access `$(element).offset().top` directly, and you'll always get the correct value.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/we5FP/